# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de guardar fechas?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, firebase

Quisiera sacarme esta duda con respecto a las fechas con JavascSript o más bien con Moment.js.

Tengo un calendario donde guardo eventos. Si selecciono una hora (por ejemplo 21 diciembre a las 8:00). Esta fecha está en Moment.js y la convierto a UNIX para guardarla en Firebase. Luego esta fecha quiero recuperar por lo cual vuelvo a convertir ahora de UNIX a Date.

Es aquí donde veo diferencia: la hora ya no son las 8:00 sino las 21:00 del día anterior. Es por ello que me gustaría saber cuál es la forma correcta de guardar fechas y luego leerla sin que la zona horaria sea un dolor de cabeza.

Para guardar tomo lo siguiente:

timeAll contiene:

```
_d: Mon Dec 21 2015 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora est. Sudamérica Pacífico)
_f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"
_i: "2015-12-21T08:00:00"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: true
_locale: q
_pf: Object
__proto__: m
```

y ésta es la función agregar:

```
vm.new.$add({
    title: 'Titulo: '+ Evento.Fecha.timeAll.format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'),
    startsAt:Evento.Fecha.timeAll.unix() ,
    endsAt:Evento.Fecha.timeAll.endOf("hour").unix(),
});
```

Esto son los datos en la base de datos:

```
endsAt: 1450745999 
startsAt: 1450742400
title: "aaa:21.12.2015 21:00"
```

Al rescatar desde la base de datos, esto es lo que obtengo:

```
// Antes item.startsAt : Tue, 22 Dec 2015 00:00:00 GMT

item.startsAt = moment.unix(item.startsAt).toDate();

// despues item.startsAt = startsAt: Mon Dec 21 2015 21:00:00 GMT-0300
```

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías poner el código que utilizaste para que podamos replicarlo?

Comment: Utiliza el formato de tu base de datos, en este caso utilizas Javascript en tu vista, que es la quien se encarga de la capa de vista. No conozco firebase por eso no pongo esto como respuesta, pero también seria bueno saber que hay entre el firebase y el Html Usas PHP? Java? ASP?

Comment: Probablemente no estás guardando el dato de la zona horaria junto con tu fecha/hora, con lo cual al volver a tomarla está cambiando. Te recomiendo siempre convertir la fecha a UTC para guardarla para no depender de la zona horaria del servidor. Luego puedes volver a convertirla a hora local cuando la muestras.

Comment: ahora agregue un poco de codigo

Comment: @gbellmann en el post muestro como se pasa al unix

Comment: Crea un [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) en www.jsfiddle.net o similar

Comment: El mcve mejor crearlo directamente en la pregunta y no en un servicio externo. Los enlaces externos se pueden romper y el editor tiene el botón de "fragmento JavaScript/HTML/CSS" que da las mismas opciones.

Comment: @LuisRuizFigueroa los valores que muestras como antes (Tue, 22 Dec 2015 00:00:00 GMT) y después (Mon Dec 21 2015 21:00:00 GMT-0300) son el mismo momento de tiempo. La diferencia es que el antes es GMT y el después es GMT-3. Puedes convertir entre ambos con las funciones de manipulación (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/)

Comment: @gbellmann se que son las mismas , pero como comente el evento que se guardo se supone que es a las 8:00

Comment: No estas usando la misma zona horaria al convertirla, moment tiene un plugin de zonas horarias. Dependiendo de lo que quieres hacer con la fecha guardar el string completo debe ser y quiza mas confiable.

Comment: @LuisRuizFigueroa en el código que muestras nunca veo una hora que sea a las 8... Estás usando TimeAll, que tiene el valor de las 21 GMT-3, que después recuperas correctamente. Evidentemente te está faltando mostrarnos el código anterior a todo eso.

Comment: @gbellmann creo que Luis se refiere a la parte de `_i: "2015-12-21T08:00:00"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No tienes ningún error, la estas guardando bien, el problema no es como la guardas sino como la muestras.
Ambas fechas son la misma fecha

```
Tue, 22 Dec 2015 00:00:00 GMT

Mon Dec 21 2015 21:00:00 GMT-0300
```

Y ya que usas **[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)** puedes usar una función como esta para convertir la visualización en otra time zone

```
function toTimeZone(time, zone) {
    var format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';
    return moment(time, format).tz(zone).format(format);
}
```

También puedes usar [timezone.JS](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js) para los mismo cambiar de zona horaria de acuerdo a la cultura

```
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date("2012/04/10 10:10:30 +0000", 'Europe/London');
dt.setTimezone("Asia/Jakarta");

console.debug(dt); //return formatted date-time in asia/jakarta
```

Comment: se supone que eso me retornara la hora a 22 de diciembre a las 8:00 AM ?

Comment: Básicamente  tu específicas la zona horaria en que quieres ver la hora, dado que es la misma hora si deseas verla en GMT dirá 22/Dec 00:00 y si deseas verla en GMT-3 21/Dec 21:00. El primer ejemplo es una función ya creada que puedes llamar para convertir una hora de una zona a otra.  El segundo ejemplo lo hacer por medio del **culture** pero es solo un ejemplo porque no se cual es el culture donde tienes tu programa.

Comment: entiendo, pero si yo agrego mi zona horaria me va a dar las 21:00 , pero como explique mas arriba la hora que yo seleccione para que sea guardada fue a las 8:00 AM

Comment: @JuanK, una consulta Off Topic, ¿usted era el usuario con el avatar de Link en solocodigo?

Comment: @manix Si, de hecho soy. Lo que pasa es que ya no voy al foro pero mi usuario sigue vigente 

Comment: @JuanK claro,  yo era usuario por los años 2005-2008, un gustazo encontrarlo aquí.  Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La manera correcta de guardar una fecha en una base de datos es en `UTC` en formato `ISO`. Para esto puedes usar un método que posee `Moment.js` =>

`moment(myDate).utc();`

Si deseas luego llevar esta fecha a tu zona horaria, es tan solo convertirla a un `Date` normal de `Javascript`, ejemplo =>

```
var utcDate = moment(myDate).utc();
var myDate = utcDate.toDate();
```